# How to use Power BI Embedded?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

After reading the Power BI Embedded [documentation](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-embedding-content/), I have a Bunch of Questions.

How should a Front End Developer,who has very little knowledge in `Backend` Technologies but has knowledge of Power BI approach power BI embedded?

What should I do with the code generated in the Embed code sample?

If I have the Embed Id,Report ID and Embed URL,Can this Embedding be done without any Back End?

I'm trying to embed a report in a website where users do not require a Power BI account to view them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with the person who asked the question. Recently, I spent a few weeks to get an embedded solution to work as I wanted to. There's a lot of documentation but it really isn't that clear on some things.

The easiest way to present your report on a web page is Publish to web as described here: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-publish-to-web/

There are some disadvantages though, as described in the link. The main thing is, there's no real security with Publish to web. If someone knows the URL of the report, they are able to see it without any credentials.

The second way is to use the embedded APIs and all the things related to it, as described in the link you posted. And yes, you might need some `backend` code as well.

To sum up, you need an Azure AD tenant and one account in the tenant with Power BI Pro subscription.
First, you register a `PowerBI` app to Azure and write down the client id you get from that (https://dev.powerbi.com/apps). This is just to make the authentication work correctly.

Then you'll need to login to Azure portal and update the permission settings of the app you registered (https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-register-app/#apply-permissions-to-your-application-within-azure-ad).

Now you can publish the report to Power BI service. You should write down the report, workspace and `dataset` `GUIDs` after you have published the report. These `GUIDs` are visible in the URL when you click on the report and the report `dataset`.

After all of this, you're able to use the examples provided. You should have all the settings and id's that examples need. The `backend` stuff might be needed, if you'd like to use a single master account in the authentication.

Comment: Thanks Man, I have one more question.
Can the authentication be done in the front end using Power BI Rest API ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think it's not possible to authenticate without a small piece of backend code, something like described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/get-azuread-access-token. It might be possible with some redirects to Office365 and back, but I doubt it

Comment: Using the old Power BI embedded azure workspaces, some customers don't like the embedded url to be https://embedded.powerbi.com saying it involves connecting to an external Office account. Do you think https://app.powerbi.com is any difference in not being related to office 365 ?

Answer (score 1):

"official" samples available [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples) and [here](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html) and "unofficial" sample is available [here](https://snobu.github.io/powerbi-embed-v2/). 
If you could rephrase your question to address exactly the place where you're stuck, including some (not) working code samples, you could get a better quality help.